# In Scala, how come `println(1,2)` works?

Tags: scala, tuples, implicit-conversion

In Scala (2.7.7final), the `Predef.println` method is defined as having the following signature:

```
def println (x : Any) : Unit
```

How come, then that the following works:

```
scala> println(1,2)  
(1,2)
```

Does the compiler automatically convert a comma-separated list of arguments into a Tuple? By what magic? Is there an implicit conversion going on here, and if so, which one?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, the compiler will attempt to convert comma separated arguments into tuples, if there are no appropriate multi-argument methods and a single appropriate one-argument method.  It's not an implicit conversion, just a compiler hack.  This is a somewhat controversial feature, and will probably undergo changes going forward, as work is planned around unifying the treatment of tuples and argument lists.

Comment: Could anyone provide a reference to the controversy? I'd like to see where this is going.

Comment: Ah, http://scala-programming-language.1934581.n4.nabble.com/Unifying-Tuple-types-and-function-parameters-td2012123.html is a start.