# Why and how is Scala treating a tuple specially when calling a one arg function?

Tags: scala, tuples

[scala coalesces multiple function call parameters into a Tuple -- can this be disabled?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2850902) discusses Scala creating a tuple to bind to one arg function. This results in

```
scala> println(1, 2)
(1,2)
```

The answer says that the compiler allows one arg functions to be called with no parens, so that logically this is a call to println with a tuple.

But println cannot be called with a single tuple parameter

```
scala> val t = (1, 2)
t: (Int, Int) = (1,2)

scala> println t
<console>:6: error: value t is not a member of Unit
       println t
           ^
```

so something else is going on. Why are tuples special here?

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3526156

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2850902/scala-coalesces-multiple-function-call-parameters-into-a-tuple-can-this-be-dis/2852147#2852147

Comment: So the tuple case is special because the compiler parses it that way - but why?

Comment: I see your answer below, thanks.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Contrary to [this explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2850902/scala-coalesces-multiple-function-call-parameters-into-a-tuple-can-this-be-dis/2851212#2851212), Scala *parses* `println(1,2)` (or `Console println (1,2)` for that matter) the same way it parses any two-argument method call. Later, the compiler transforms the call by wrapping the method arguments in a tuple to match the actual method type signature.

If the compiler did not do this, perfectly valid expressions like `Console println (1,2)` would fail to compile because `println` does not take multiple arguments.  There are also [other valid use cases](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5985076/scala-generic-class-supporting-function-of-multiple-arities) for this behavior.

Consider an expression like `foo bar (1,2)` from the compiler's point of view, keeping in mind that Scala has special syntax that allows you to drop the `.` and the parens on method calls.  This could be a call to a two-argument `bar` method with arguments `1` and `2`, or it could be a call to a one-argument `bar` method with a single tuple-valued argument.  The parser doesn't know anything about the `bar` method, so it just parses as a two-argument method call.

During the type checking phase, suppose the compiler determines that `foo` has no two-argument `bar` method but that it does have a one-argument `bar` method whose signature is compatible with the tuple interpretation. Since there is no other valid interpretation, it assumes that this is what you meant and transforms the two arguments into a tuple. Note that if there is a two-argument `bar` method, even one that is incompatible with the actual arguments, the typer *will not* perform the auto-tupling transformation.

Comment: So as I understand your answer, the compiler is not using the no-parens case, but rather the parens case with later transformation of a list of args to a tuple in order to match `println(o: Any)`

Comment: And further that the transformation to a tuple is there to allow the writing of functions that take variable arguments.

Comment: No, variable arguments are unrelated.  I'll edit the answer to make it more clear.

Comment: Rather than variable arguments I should have said function of any arity, and rather than writing them, what, manipulating them?

Answer (score 0):

A statement, that you can omit parens when calling on-arg function is not always true.
Note, that:

```
    println "hello"
    val puts = (s: String) => println(s)
    puts "hello"
```

don't work either, despite that there's no tuple here.
It works if you use infix notation. Following statements work great:

```
    Console println "hello"
    val t = (1, 2)
    Console println t
    puts apply "hello" // puts is defined above
```

Comment: I was a little surprised when I discovered that I can only omit parens when using infix too, as it seems to make some DSLs a little stilted eg `result should equal(42)` but I guess that the parser may need a little help. But this still doesn't explain how the tuple is being bound...