# How do I tell Scala to use the right Java constructor?

Tags: scala

I'm trying to use JodaTime in Scala. So I did

```
import org.joda.time.DateTime

val dt = new DateTime(2011, 10, 8, 18, 30) // try to set to 6:30 pm, Oct 8, 2011
```

Unfortunately, Scala thinks I'm trying to use the DateTime(Object) constructor instead of the 5 int constructor, and, not surprisingly, a Tuple5 is not the kind of Object JodaTime was expecting.

How do I tell Scala to use the 5-int constructor?

Todd

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's probable that you're using an older version of JodaTime.  The constructor you are trying to use didn't exist until [JodaTime 2.0](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/api-release/org/joda/time/DateTime.html#DateTime%28int,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int%29).

Older versions of JodaTime had no 5 param ctor.  Since Scala can't find one, it assumes that you're attempting to pass in a tuple, which matches the Object ctor.  You can find more details in [this excellent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5997553/why-and-how-is-scala-treating-a-tuple-specially-when-calling-a-one-arg-function/5998559#5998559).

Comment: You're exactly right. I was looking at Javadocs for 2.0, but the dependency I was relying on was for 1.6.2.

Comment: Sorry. I tried to up-vote and don't have sufficient experience. I didn't realize I could check! (Which explains why I don't have sufficient experience to up-vote.) :-)