# Adding value to Scala map

Tags: scala, dictionary

Why does this work:

```
val x = Map[Int,Int]()
val y = (1, 0)
x + y
```

but not this?

```
val x = Map[Int,Int]()
x + (1, 0)
```

The error produced is:

```
<console>:11: error: type mismatch;
found   : Int(1)
required: (Int, ?)
          x + (1,0)
               ^
```

If I were to enter `(1,0)` into the REPL, it correctly types it as `(Int,Int)`.

I should add that this works fine:

```
x + (1 -> 0)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is an ambiguity caused by the similarity between the notation for tuples and the one for parameter lists :

`x + (1,0)` is notation for `x.+(1,0)` but sadly there is no method on `x` that takes two `Int` parameters. What you want is `x.+((1,0))`, i.e. `x + ((1,0))`.

There is something in Scala called auto-tupling, see [this question and answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5997553/why-and-how-is-scala-treating-a-tuple-specially-when-calling-a-one-arg-function), which rewrites, for example, `println (1,2)` to `println((1,2))`. Except this will not work here because the `+` method takes a variable number of arguments and not a single  one like `println`.

You get that strange error message because it expect every value in your parameter list `(1,0)` to be a tuple, as in `myMap + ((1,2), (1,3), (3,4))`. It finds an `Int` instead of a `(Int, Int)`, hence the error.

Comment: Thanks for the great explanation to go along with the answer!

Answer (score 2):

add another pair of parentheses to make it work:

```
val x = Map[Int,Int]()
x + ((1, 0))
```