# Scala println adding parentheses in output

Tags: scala

I'm taking my first steps in scala, and here is an "hello world"-like code :

```
package test
object Main {
def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
        println("Blabla something : " + 3)
        println("Blabla something : " , 3)
    }
}
```

Here is the output I get :

```
Blabla something : 3
(Blabla something : ,3)
```

Why are there parentheses printed in the second line, along with the "," ?
I was expecting the same output as in the first line.

***Note*** : I tried searching for *scala println parentheses* and such, but all I get is posts on how to remove the parentheses from the code, not from the output.

Comment: Similar to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5997553/why-and-how-is-scala-treating-a-tuple-specially-when-calling-a-one-arg-function). What happens here is "auto-tupling" (see @LimbSoup's answer)

Comment: @0__ I was indeed suspecting some feature of scala playing it's part here, but I had no idea which one. I'll dig into that thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To see this in action you could do something like this in the REPL:

```
scala> import scala.reflect.runtime.universe.TypeTag
scala> def printz[T](x: T)(implicit tT: TypeTag[T]) = { val v = x; println(s"$v : $tT")}

scala> printz("Blabla something : " , 3)
(Blabla something : ,3) : TypeTag[(String, Int)]
```

`TypeTag[(String, Int)]` hints at the tuple `(String, Int)`.

Comment: +1 That seems cool, would you (briefly) explain what happens in your `printz` function ?

Comment: TypeTags are a way of reifying types at runtime ([TypeTags and Manifests](http://bit.ly/1pBwiOX)) and captured as an implicit `tT`. So `printz` is like `println` except it also prints the typetag of some type `T` (type of value `x` that is passed to the method) along with the value `x`. In general one should not use reflection. But here it is a great way to find what's going on under the hood as `println` takes `Any`. (I'd argue that the behaviour shown is actually a mistake and should have been flagged but can't be because any value works for println.) Does that help?

Answer (score 2):

The comma has a special meaning. The compiler is interpreting the arguments of `println("Blabla something : " , 3)` as a `Tuple`, because of the comma. In particular, one with type `(String, Int)`.

Answer (score 1):

When you call

```
println("Blabla something : " , 3)
```

the following happens:

1. `println` only expects one argument. Also, in Scala functions with one argument can be called without parentheses. That means that `println` interpretes everything after it as one parameter and adds parentheses around it, and your command is getting translated as:

   println(("Blabla something : " , 3))
2. When the argument given to `println` is not a String, it is converted to a String by calling its `toString` method, which exists for every object (in one or another form). For a Tuple (which is the argument given to `println` in this example) the default `toString` method just prints the tuple as a pair of values, surrounded with quotes, which is exactly what you see.

Comment: Functions may never be called without parentheses, and the only time methods can be called without parentheses is with infix notation, which isn't what is happening here. `println "x"` is a syntax error, though `Console println "x"` works. That said, this is otherwise a correct description of what happens.

Comment: @wingedsubmariner I'm not sure I get it. Are you saying that the parentheses are added for the tuple and not the function ? (Wouldn't that be weird ?)

Comment: @nha Scala doesn't interpret `println(a, b)` as passing the tuple `(a, b)` to `println`, it sees it as an attempt to pass two parameters to `println`, discovers that `println` doesn't take two parameters but will accept a tuple (the type of its parameter is `Any` which is a supertype of all the tuple types) and so wraps the parameters into a tuple, making `println((a, b))`. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5998559/1224627).

Comment: @wingedsubmariner OK I get it now. I didn't realise that println took only one parameter. Thanks for the clarification.