# Scala represent an Option tuple

Tags: scala

How to explicitly set an Option which is a tuple of a certain type to be None?

```
scala> var c = Some(1,1)
c: Some[(Int, Int)] = Some((1,1))

scala> c = None
<console>:11: error: type mismatch;
 found   : None.type
 required: Some[(Int, Int)]
       c = None
           ^

scala> None()
<console>:11: error: None.type does not take parameters
       None()
           ^

scala> c = None()
<console>:11: error: None.type does not take parameters
       c = None()
               ^

scala> c = None.Int
<console>:11: error: value Int is not a member of object None
       c = None.Int
                ^

scala> c = None(Int, Int)
<console>:11: error: None.type does not take parameters
       c = None(Int, Int)
               ^

scala> c = (None, None)
<console>:11: error: type mismatch;
 found   : (None.type, None.type)
 required: Some[(Int, Int)]
       c = (None, None)
```

Comment: Just declare the type explicitly at first usage. The inference is too precise/restrictive here - Some instead of Option. var c: Option[(Int, Int)] = Some((1,1))

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As @DidierDupont pointed it out - your first declaration of `c` infers that its type is `Some[(Int, Int)]`, instead of `Option[(Int, Int)]`. Declare `c` as the following and you should be fine:

```
var c: Option[(Int, Int)] = Some((1, 1))
```

or, as Gabriele Petronella pointed out, simply

```
var c = Option((1, 1))
```

Comment: or just `val c: Option((1, 1))`. Also this is using auto-tupling, which might not be the best idea here

Comment: What Gabriele said, plus this explanation - http://stackoverflow.com/a/5998559/409976.

Comment: @KevinMeredith I've removed auto-tupling. Thanks for the reference.

Answer (score 2):

You declared c = Some(1,1) which set the type to Some. You really wanted a type of Option, so try by declaring the type:

```
var c:Option[(Int,Int)] = Some(1,1)
c = None
```

Comment: What is the type is a return parameter of a method?

Comment: If the method is defined to return type, Some, you can still declare the variable as type Option.

Answer (score 0):

Actually this is not about tuples. Following code will not work:

```
var a = Some("String")
a = None
```

because Scala has a type Some[T] which is a subclass of Option[T] just like None, this means Some[T] and None types are at same inheritance level. So from this we can say that declaring type explicitly as others mentioned will do work.

```
var a: Option[(Int, Int)] = Some((1, 1))
```

you can check more if you want at: [Scala Option](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.Option)