# Some with multiple arguments creates Option of Tuple

Tags: scala, scala-collections, scala-option

How does the following code work in Scala ?

```
scala> Some(2,true,3, false)
res13: Some[(Int, Boolean, Int, Boolean)] = Some((2,true,3,false))
```

I don't see an apply method defined for some which can take more than one argument.

Comment: see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5997553/why-and-how-is-scala-treating-a-tuple-specially-when-calling-a-one-arg-function http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3526156/in-scala-how-come-println1-2-works  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2850902/scala-coalesces-multiple-function-call-parameters-into-a-tuple-can-this-be-di/2852147#2852147

Comment: thanks for the references! This is quite surprising.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Multiple arguments are implicitly adapted to make a tuple if they don't otherwise fit; this will happen for any method, there's nothing special about `Some` here:

```
def doSomething(a: Any) = {...}
doSomething(2, true, 3, false)
```

You can (and, I would argue, should; it's a misfeature that tends to mask programming errors) make the compiler emit a warning if this happens, by passing the flag `-Ywarn-adapted-args`. See [here](http://tpolecat.github.io/2014/04/11/scalac-flags.html) for a list of similar recommended flags.

Answer (score 1):

`Some(2,true,3, false)` is syntactic sugar for `Some(new Tuple4(2,true,3, false))`.

That's why the type is `Some[(Int, Boolean, Int, Boolean)]`

It works until 22 elements and if you need more, then you can use a collection, not a tuple.